# Why do we require the (whole) domain to be simply connected in Cauchy's theorem, residue theorem, etc.?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

### Main Question

A very common form of Cauchy's integral theorem is

---

Let $A\subset\mathbf{C}$ be simply connected and open, $f:A\rightarrow\mathbf{C}$ analytic, $I$ a compact interval, and $\gamma:I\rightarrow A$ continuous (or whatever) with $\gamma(I)\subset A$. Then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$.

---

I think it would also suffice (and not make the proof any harder) to assume that $\gamma$ is homotopic in $A$ to a point without requiring that $A$ is simply connected. Am I correct?

If so, why is it never (or seldom) stated this way? The same applies to the residue theorem and other related theorems of complex analysis.

### Related

I would be less surprised if the following statement was completely obvious:

---

Let $A\subset\mathbf{C}$ open, $I$ a compact interval, and $\gamma:I\rightarrow A$ a continuous path homotopic in $A$ to a point. Then there exists $U\subset A$ open and simply connected with $\gamma(I)\subset U$.

---

I suspect this is true, and I have a vague idea how to prove it. But it's not a one-liner and I don't remember seeing it in any textbook. Am I missing something?

Comment: You might like Stewart and Tall's "Complex Analysis", or Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable".

Comment: Three great answers, complementing each other nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @Dap: Thanks. I've come across Conway's book a few times and had a good impression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Let $A\subset\mathbf{C}$ open, $I$ a compact interval, and $\gamma:I\rightarrow A$ a continuous path homotopic in $A$ to a point. Then there exists $U\subset A$ open and simply connected with $\gamma(I)\subset U$.

Let's try this curve, where $A$ is the complement of $\{0\}$.

[image: curve]

Certainly $\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z} = 0$, where $\gamma$ is that contour.

Comment: Very nice example. You can still do this with the "simply connected" version, if you cover C* with itself twice via z -> z². The lifted curve is then contained in a simply connected region and the integral over the lifted function vanishes by the "simply connected" Cauchy Theorem. I don't know how to do formalise this in general, but it seems like something that could work. On the other hand all that lifting is already so much topology, that you might as well go with the homotopy version.

Comment: Actually, you could always just lift to the universal cover, so a version of @Stefan's conjecture using lifts to the universal cover should be true.

Answer (score 8):

In fact, I would argue Cauchy's integral theorem in the proper form is the fact the following three statements are equivalent for $\gamma$ a loop in some open set $\Omega$:

1. The loop $\gamma$ is *nullhomologous* in $\Omega$, that is, it has index (or winding number) zero around every point in the complement of $\Omega$,
2. The induced map $f\in \mathcal O(\Omega)\longmapsto \int_\gamma fdz\in \mathbb C$ is identically zero,
3. For each $f\in \mathcal O(\Omega)$, Cauchy's formula holds for $\gamma$:
   $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z}d\xi = I(\gamma,z) f(z).$$

Since all nullhomotopic loops are nullhomologous (by the homotopic invariance of the integral) you obtain your form of Cauchy's integral theorem. One argument in favour of putting Cauchy's theorem in the above form is that it can be restated in the following form: let $H_1(\Omega)$ be the space of chains in $\Omega$ (formal sums of loops) modulo nullhomologous chains, and let $H^1(\Omega)$ be the space of holomorphic functions modulo functions that are derivatives. Then there is a nondegenerate bilinear form
$$H_1(\Omega)\otimes H^1(\Omega)\to \mathbb C$$
that takes the class of a chain $\Gamma$ in $\Omega$ and the class of a holomorphic function $f$ in $\Omega$ and assigns it to $\int_\Gamma fdz \in \mathbb C$. This is a version of de Rham's theorem in this rather simple case.

Comment: I doubt that there is a "proper form". This is obviously the sort of thing you want to have as your understanding of the theorem when you've studied complex variables, and some point-set topology, and a bit of algebraic topology, and something about manifolds...but is it the "proper form" for the sophomore who is encountering it for the first time? Maybe not.

Comment: @JohnHughes I'm not claiming students will understand the connection of the statement with all of what I/you mentioned, just that it is a proper way to state it and produce further comment of it so that, when the time is right, the student will indeed understand it from the point of view I suggested.

Comment: I dunno. I learned it the "basic" way from Churchill's book, but by the time I knew what null homotopic meant, I was able to see that this was the real requirement, and null-homologous followed pretty quickly. And since I'd already seen deRham for forms on smooth manifolds, that part came fairly naturally as well. I think my students are often good at generalizing, but not so good at "particularizing". While the "small" theorem naturally is a consequence of the "big" one, many students have trouble seeing that. And they also miss the experience of having the "Aha!" that deeper things abound.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the reason that the theorem is usually stated the way you wrote is this: "simply connected domain" is pretty easy to understand (or so students think), while homotopy is harder, and doesn't need to be introduced for any other purpose just yet. And since the book is going to apply this theorem to things like a disk (over and over!) or a rectangle (sometimes) or the upper half-plane (pretty often), it's easier to make a claim about a domain you'll be using over and over than about a particular curve.

In particular, many of the "evaluate this improper integral on the real line using residues", in which you draw ever-larger semidisk, etc., use the same domain for infinitely many semi-circle-plus-diameter paths. It's conceptually far simpler to prove *once* that the whole domain is simply connected than to prove that each of those infinitely many  paths is null-homotopic.  (Sure, the null-homotopy is obvious, but I think you get my point)

That's only a guess --- it's hard to know why nyone chooses a particular way of presenting an idea --- but it certainly matches what *I* would want to do in a basic complex analysis course.

As for your second statement... I'm not so sure I believe that's true. I'm thinking about things like the complement of the topologists's sine curve, or the complement of the Alexander horned sphere ... I know that neither of those is really a counterexample, and the fact that the interval is compact is likely to help with the original claim...but I don't see the proof yet at all.

Comment: Even more extreme: some treatments only use "star domains".

Comment: Did you see GEdgar's easy counter-example? =)

Comment: Indeed. I wish he'd written it a few minutes earlier. I guess my instincts were good, but doubts were the wrong ones. :)